# How to generate a matrix of circular-splits?

Tags: r, split

I have an ordering of populations along a circle. Let Z be an ordering of all my 5 populations named "A".. "E".

```
Z = c("A","B","C","D","E")
```

A split is one possibility to seperate all populations into two sets, where each set contain at least one population. THe splits that put D on one side and EABC on the other side is called Splits `D|EABC`. I don't want to make any different between `D|EABC` and `EABC|D`. The split `D|EABC` is represented by the green line on the figure below. All the lines below represent all the existing splits.

[image: Circular Splits of 5 populations]

My goal is to generate all the splits possible and to build up a matrix that tells me whether a given pair of population is found in the same set of in the opposite set when a given split occurs. For example split `AB | DCE` put population `A` and `C` on two different sets but does not put `A` and `B` in two different sets. From the vector `Z`, I aim to build the following kind of matrix, where a `1` indicates that the two populations are in the same set and a `0` indicate that the two population are different sets

[image: Splits matrix (not complete)]

How can I do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all the ten splits with their complements:

```
first <- sapply(1:10, function(n) 
          LETTERS[1:5][combn(1:5,2)[1,n]:(combn(1:5,2)[2,n]-.1) ] )
comps <- sapply(first , function(f) setdiff( LETTERS[1:5] , f)  )
```

These are the ten pairings:

```
> pairings <- sapply(1:10, function(n) LETTERS[1:5][c(combn(1:5,2)[1,n], combn(1:5,2)[2,n]) ] )
> pairings
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] "a"  "a"  "a"  "a"  "b"  "b"  "b"  "c"  "c"  "d"  
[2,] "b"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "c"  "d"  "e"  "d"  "e"  "e"
```

This should deliver the matrix:

```
outer(1:10, 1:10 , FUN= Vectorize( function(x,y){   # Either:
            (pairings[1,x] %in% first[[y]] & pairings[2,x] %in% comps[[y]] ) |  # Or
            (pairings[2,x] %in% first[[y]] & pairings[1,x] %in% comps[[y]] ) }))

       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
[10,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you need to matrix an R logical matrix into 1/0 just add 0 to it.